# The add button is below the navigation panel

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, rightbarbuttonitem

Can someone help me with how I could inline the add button with the navigation panel? [Its shown below the panel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4h3m.png)

This is the code I used:

```
let add = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: nil)

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = add
```

Comment: Set `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false`

Comment: I tried ```self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false``` but the display is still the same. The add button is still underneath